# How to get name of currently running tasks in ssis package

Tags: ssis

I have four tasks in sequence in a SSIS package. How to get name of currently running tasks after every 10 minutes?

Comment: Isn't the execution history report enough? It will show you what's already happend in an execution, with execution times. If you need the current task, you probably need it *now*. The 10-minute old record is already in the report

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script you can use to fetch running package_name with SQL Job agent. You could then make a ssis package to extract this data, and then set it up in an SQL JOB Agent which runs every 10 minutes. You can see the task name in message_source_name

**Current running package with taskname:**

```
USE SSISDB
GO
/*
Configuration
*/
    -- Filter data by execution id (use NULL for no filter)

-- Show only Child Packages or everyhing
DECLARE @showOnlyChildPackages BIT = 0;
-- Show only message from a specific Message Source
DECLARE @messageSourceName NVARCHAR(MAX)= '%'

-- Filter data by project name (use % for no filter)
DECLARE @projectNamePattern NVARCHAR(100) = '%'
-- Filter data by package name (use % for no filter)
DECLARE @packageNamePattern NVARCHAR(100) = '%'
-- Filter data by execution id (use NULL for no filter)
DECLARE @executionIdFilter BIGINT = NULL;
with running as (

/*
Implementation
*/
-- Show last 15 executions
SELECT TOP 15
e.execution_id, 
e.project_name,
e.package_name,
e.project_lsn,
e.status, 
status_desc = CASE e.status 
WHEN 1 THEN 'Created'
WHEN 2 THEN 'Running'
WHEN 3 THEN 'Cancelled'
WHEN 4 THEN 'Failed'
WHEN 5 THEN 'Pending'
WHEN 6 THEN 'Ended Unexpectedly'
WHEN 7 THEN 'Succeeded'
WHEN 8 THEN 'Stopping'
WHEN 9 THEN 'Completed'
END,
e.start_time,
e.end_time,
elapsed_time_min = datediff(mi, e.start_time, e.end_time)
FROM 
catalog.executions e 
WHERE 
e.project_name LIKE @projectNamePattern
AND
e.package_name LIKE @packageNamePattern
AND
e.execution_id = ISNULL(@executionIdFilter, e.execution_id)
and e.status = 2


)



select * from running a 
inner join 
(
    SELECT top 1 * FROM catalog.event_messages em 
WHERE ((em.operation_id = @executionIdFilter) OR @executionIdFilter IS NULL) 
--AND (em.event_name IN ('OnInformation', 'OnError', 'OnWarning'))
AND (package_path LIKE CASE WHEN @showOnlyChildPackages = 1 THEN '\Package' ELSE '%' END)
AND (em.message_source_name like @messageSourceName)
order by operation_id desc,message_time desc
)
 b on a.execution_id = b.operation_id
```